# millis Vs inputStage(executionTimeMillisEstimate) Vs needTime Vs execStats(executionTimeMillisEstimate)

Tags: mongodb

When I am running the below command for profiling

```
db.system.profile.find().sort({ts:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

I am getting too many time variables

1. millis
2. inputStage(executionTimeMillisEstimate)
3. needTime
4. xecStats(executionTimeMillisEstimate)

I am not sure which one is actually the time required by the query.

Please suggest.

Comment: There is a manual page [Database Profiler Output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/) which has all the descriptions and specifically [`system.profile.millis`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#system.profile.millis) *"The time in milliseconds from the perspective of the mongod from the beginning of the operation to the end of the operation."* which means that one is the "total" time of the whole operation. The others refer to different stages in the query plan.

Comment: @NeilLunn please write as an answer, so i can accept your answer as best